# $g\left(s+t\right)=g\left(s\right)\cdot g\left(t\right)$ imply that $g\left(x\right)=g\left(1\right)^{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Im trying to prove that for every $x\in\mathbb{Q}\ \mbox{the following is true:}\ \ \ \ $   $g\left(s+t\right)=g\left(s\right)\cdot g\left(t\right)\Rightarrow$  $g\left(x\right)=g\left(1\right)^{x}$

I've managed to prove that it's true for every $x\in\mathbb{N}$ really easy by induction:

$g\left(x+1\right)=g\left(x\right)\cdot g\left(1\right)\overset{\text{i.h}}{=}g\left(1\right)^{x}\cdot g\left(1\right)=g\left(1\right)^{x+1}$

but im having trobule to extend it to $\mathbb{Q}$

any advices ?

Comment: Now, try extend it to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: After that, proof that holds for $1/q,\ q\in\mathbb{Z},q\neq0$.

Comment: Finally, you can proof for all $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Curiosity: If we have the function continuos, then we can proof the property for $\mathbb{R}$!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
$$g(1)=g(3/3)=g(1/3+1/3+1/3)=g(1/3)^3$$

Comment: In this case, he has to proof first that the property holds for all $1/q$, with $q\in\mathbb{Z},\ q\neq0$.